# ctx.author.avatar_url does not work if I remove the avatar output

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
emb.set_footer(text = 'Был забанен администратором {}'.format(ctx.author.name), icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
```

I want to output the avatar of the user who executed a command. An example can be found here:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

It should be `icon_url=ctx.author.avatar` for the `discord.py>=2.0.0`. 
For `discord.py<=1.7.3`, it is how you wrote. So, you might watch/view an outdated code snippet or tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

As both the other answers mention: You need `ctx.author.avatar` or `ctx.author.avatar.url` instead of `ctx.author.avatar_url`.

However, this method will not work if the user did not set an avatar. To encounter the possible problem, you could also **use the following:**

```py
emb.set_footer(text=f'Был забанен администратором - {ctx.author.name}', icon_url = ctx.author.default_avatar.url)
```

If you still want to keep your old method, the following works just fine:

```py
emb.set_footer(text=f'Был забанен администратором - {ctx.author.name}', icon_url = ctx.author.avatar.url)
```

You can find the API Reference here: [discord.abc.User](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=avatar#discord.abc.User.avatar)

Answer (score 0):

#### In the latest discord.py version (`2.3.1`), to show an avatar url, we need to use `ctx.author.avatar.url`

### So the code you need to use is:

```
emb.set_footer(f'Был забанен администратором - {ctx.author} ',icon_url = ctx.author.avatar.url)
```